# foreach with an AND logical operator

Tags: php, foreach

about foreach, why it doesnt accept the AND logical operator?
I've already use the "&&" and I'm getting the same error.
do I need to create another foreach?

```
<?php

$txt_name=$_REQUEST['text_name'];
$txt_value=$_REQUEST['text_value'];

if (!empty($txt_name) AND ($txt_value)) {
    foreach ($txt_name AS $x)&&($txt_value AS $y)  {

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("test1"); 
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
        $score = mysql_real_escape_string($y);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_test (testname, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')");
        mysql_close($con);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Dunno if I am missing something but I cannot see any for loops in your sample code. Can you post more complete code please? Then we can see why you are attempting to use `and`

Comment: what im trying to do is to insert multiple value on sql but the problem is why foreach does not accept the AND logical operator

Comment: Because it's the AND logical operator, and the two possible values it can return are true and false, neither of which can be iterated through. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, but try:

```
if (!empty($txt_name) && !empty($txt_value)) {
    foreach ($txt_name AS $k => $x) {
        $y =$txt_value[$k];
```

Comment: why do you use [$k] on $y=$txt_value[$k]; ? does that mean the $k is the value of $txt_name?

Comment: I'm guessing that both $txt_name and $txt_value are arrays of the same length, and with the same keys. $k is the key in the $txt_name array, and $txt_value[$k] is looking to find a corresponding entry with the same key in the $txt_value array.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't it accept the AND logical operator?

`foreach` does not execute a logic operation. That's not how it works.

> Do I need to create another foreach?

Yes

`foreach` is a simplified way of writing a more complicated `for` loop:

```
foreach ( $arr as $key=>$value )
{
  ...code...
}
```

is like writing

```
$keys = array_keys( $arr );
$l = count( $arr );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++ )
{
  $key = $keys[$i];
  $value = $arr[$key];
  ...code...
}
```

Logical operations do not factor into this format.

Answer (score 3):

If they are both arrays, *foreach* only one of them and use the key to access the other array's value.

```
foreach ($txt_name AS $key => $name) {
    $value = isset($txt_value[$key]) ? $txt_value[$key] : NULL;
}
```

Comment: That is assuming that they are not arrays with different keys but still in the same order.

Comment: Judging by the OP's example, they are at least in the same order

Comment: Yes, but if the key is different then your technique will not work. An edge case I agree but still worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) would probably work best in this particular situation. This would work like the following:

```
$txt_name=$_REQUEST['text_name'];
$txt_value=$_REQUEST['text_value'];

if (!empty($txt_name) AND ($txt_value)) {
    $values = array_combine($txt_name, $txt_value);
    foreach ($values as $name => $score)  {

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("test1"); 
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $score = mysql_real_escape_string($score);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_test (testname, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')");
        mysql_close($con);

    }
}
```

This combines both variables into one array using the first as the keys and the other array as the values. You can then loop over it using a foreach nice and neatly.

If, later on, however you need to add another value into your SQL query then this technique would not work.

Answer (score 1):

The and logical operator returns true if both its operands are true, and false otherwise.

You seem to not want a logical and, but a concatenation of the two arrays. You could either repeat the loop (less memory use) or use array_merge to produce an array with the values of both arrays.

The names txt_name and txt_value make me think you want to use the two values at the same time though, loop one and retrieve into each of them (though I can't see you using the values anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use a second loop to do that.

Comment: Not true. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394986/foreach-with-an-and-logical-operator/5395136#5395136 for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($txt_name) AND ($txt_value))
{
 $i = 0;
 while(sizeof($_REQUEST['text_name']) != $i)
 {
  $x[$_REQUEST['text_name'][$i]] = $_REQUEST['text_value'][$i];
  $i++
 }

 foreach ($x AS $y)  {
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("test1"); 
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
  $score = mysql_real_escape_string($y);
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_test (testname, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')");
  mysql_close($con);

 }
}
?>
```

I make each key is a $_REQUEST['text_name'] and its value a $_REQUEST['text_value'], I hope this help.

**Note:** I made a search about fetching two arrays inside on foreach and didn't find any thing related about it, so may be php doesn't support this format.